# How Can I Edit a WordPress Site's PHP Files Without Breaking the WP Install?

Tags: php

How exactly would I edit, meaning the specific steps to edit a php files in WordPress using Filezilla or another FTP client and a text editor without breaking the WP install?

Thanks, 
Sean

Comment: You already asked this question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/277523/94498) my friend.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do I Edit WordPress PHP files Without Crashing the WP Install or Breaking the WP Theme?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/277523/how-do-i-edit-wordpress-php-files-without-crashing-the-wp-install-or-breaking-th)

Comment: Ok. I guess I was a little too over eager to get my previous question answered :-)

Answer (score 2):

You just don't do such things as any changes you will do will be lost on an upgrade.

If you need to make changes to WordPress core files (very unlikely) you should use git for version control, and properly test everything before uploading to the server, then you should disable automatic updates, and with every new version you need to merge your changes to the latest core "trunk".

### Tl;Dr

Just don't do it.

Comment: Ok, good point, Mark. You are right when you say, just don't do it. Especially since I am not a WP developer. Thanks, Mark, for the insight!